# Android: replace values of a cursor/sql query

Tags: java, android, sql, replace, adapter

In my SQL database table there are colums _id, int dayofweek, String text ...
I now, do a SQL query on that table to get a cursor to the results.
The results then are shown in a listView:

```
private void showBlocks()
{
    Cursor blocks = ttDB.getBlocks();
    startManagingCursor(blocks);

    int[] key = new int []{
            android.R.id.text1,
            android.R.id.text2 
    };

    SimpleCursorAdapter blockAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, 
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
            blocks, 
            new String[] {
                    "day",
                    "text"
                }, 
            key);

    lv1.setAdapter(blockAdapter);
 }
```

How (and where) can I now replace the integer values of dayofweek by the corresponding strings? I thought about joining two tables while querying but then it will not be multilingual any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using a `ViewBinder` via `setViewBinder()` on your `SimpleCursorAdapter`.

Or, extend `SimpleCursorAdapter`, override `bindView()` and do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you can not directly replace values .you have to store first it in list and than you can replace it with ur desired fromat